# Can I recreate this effect with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'd like to replicate the 4 shapes on [this web page](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/7/) using **HTML5 Canvas** & still have the page stretch to width & height of 100%.

Is this possible? I'm very new to Canvas.

Here is my current CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.out{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.in{
    height:75%;
    background-color:#6C2223;
}
.out:before, .out:after, .in:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25%;
    width:100%;
    height:700%;
    background-color:#9A4445;
}
.out:before{
    right:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;

     -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
    transform : rotate(-45deg);
}
.out:after{
    left:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;

    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
    transform : rotate(45deg);
}
.in:after{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:#911618;
    z-index:-1;
}
img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:3;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.text{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:4;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but rather difficult IMHO) Using canvas it is slow, you should write your filter that work with ImageData (i.e. pixels, bitmap of canvas). 
If want fast solution, use WebGL with it's shaders. It works fast and there are many 2d context libraries and filters, three.js is most famous. But... I suppose if you only want these effects you better use css3, because it's optimized.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Ultimately I'd prefer to use the 'multiply' blend mode on all 4 shapes. Is it easy to achieve the 4 shapes with WebGL?

Comment: Well, it depends on your skills. There are many tutorial like "WebGL PS blending modes", work with WebGL is similar to OpenGL, but it's not very close to me right now, so I can't write demo code for a few minutes.
http://www.nutty.ca/articles/blend_modes/   
http://www.webgl.com/2012/04/webgl-demo-photoshop-blend-modes/   
all this sources use same opengl functions, so it's better know opengl or find plugin.

Comment: Very true. If you could possibly put together a demo I would greatly appreciate it. I'm very very new to both Canvas and WebGL so any help at all would be fantastic!!

Comment: http://www.nutty.ca/articles/blend_modes/blend_modes.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only blending mode is needed, where boobs are boobs and grad is png with gradient

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px"/>
        <script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "boobs.jpg";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "grad.png";
ctx.drawImage(img2, 20, 20);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPD. Find square image 800 x 800

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"/>
        <script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";

var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "tree.png";
ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "drops.png";
ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

var img3 = new Image();
img3.src = "face.png";
ctx.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);

var idt = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 800, 800);
var xquarter = 800/2;
var yquarter = 800/2;
var x, y;
var imageWidth = 800;
var imageHeight = 800;
for(y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
        if (x > xquarter) {
            if (y > yquarter) {
                idt.data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4] += 30;
            } else {
                idt.data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 1] += 30;
            }
        } else {
            if (y > yquarter) {
                idt.data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 2] += 30;
            } else {
                idt.data[((imageWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 3] += 30;
            }
        }
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(idt,0,0);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

UPD2.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"/>
        <script>

function foo() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var xcoeff, ycoeff, maxcoeff;
    var screenWidth  = window.innerWidth;
    var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = screenWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = screenHeight;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";

    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "tree.png";
    //note that all images have same size
    xcoeff = screenWidth / img1.width;
    ycoeff = screenHeight / img1.height;
    maxcoeff = xcoeff > ycoeff ? xcoeff : ycoeff;
    ctx.scale(maxcoeff, maxcoeff);

    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);


    var img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = "drops.png";
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

    var img3 = new Image();
    img3.src = "face.png";
    ctx.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);
}
foo();
window.onresize = foo;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Is it easy to create these 4 shapes and apply the 'multply' effect to them?

Comment: To create 4 images just create 4 variables of type Image, use multiply as in first example and draw them all.

Comment: Many thanks again Ivan :-) Is it easy to set widths of 100% on these shapes?

Comment: don't understand question. 100% for what? If colours, then they are added in loop. If images to scale, yes, there are transformations for moving, rotating and scaling.

Comment: Apologies. I meant 100% width of the web page.

Comment: Still don't understand. If automatically adopt canvas to width of user's screen, then it's easy if all images have same sizes; just find scale coefficients and dynamically set width, and height, and scale. See UPD2.

Comment: I actually plan to use a full video in the background and not an image. I just wanted to try create those 4 shapes with canvas to overlay the video.